# How to enable logging for Google Task Queue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I currently have a task queue with tasks running. This is what my dashboard looks like:
[image]

When I click on 'View' (under logs on the far right), it takes me to a page that looks like this:
[image]

I am certain that there should be some logs, considering all of these tasks have been retried multiple times. I am wondering if there is some step I should have taken to enable logging on this queue?

Comment: Unless you have configured logging to include the messages from your tasks, there is no reason why logs would show up.
Also, does anything show up when you remove the Last Hour filter and use a wider timeframe? Also, does [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) help?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging by running

```
gcloud beta tasks queues create [QUEUE_ID] --log-sampling-ratio=1.0
```

You can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/logging).

Hope this helps.